# :hover border-style:none not sticking to image within SSI

Tags: html, css, image, underline

so i have this pesky problem that i can not get rid of. i have my menu and header information inserted into my html through SSI...well the menu.html page (which contains my menu) behavior correctly which means that the menu items underline on :hover as they are supposed to and the image (organization logo) does not because of a

```
.imglink:hover{
background:none;
border-style:none;
}
```

that i have inserted...but when i go to my homepage which pulls in the menu.html page through a SSI, the logo has a line under it when the :hover is invoked even though i have the above code both in the css for the menu.css and the homepage.css

any ideas?

here is my css for the menu.html page:

```
ul#menu{
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
list-style: none;
margin:2px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px;
display:block;
float:left;
width:100%;
clear:both
}

ul#menu li {
float:left;
margin:5px 0px 5px 5px;
}

ul#menu li a:link,a:visited {
display:block;
float:left;
margin:2px;
background-color: #ffffff;
color:#000000;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:.9em;
display:block;
text-align:center;
width:160px;
margin-bottom:0px;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
color:#000000;
border-bottom:1.5px solid black;
}

ul#menu li a.active {
color:#000000;
background-color:#dbdbdb;
border:1.5px solid #000000;
border-top:none;
border-left:none;
border-right:none;
}

.imglink:hover{
background:none;
border-style:none;
}
```

this is my html for the menu:

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <a href="/" class="imglink"><img class="logo" src="http://www.unifiedforuganda.com/resources/new%20u4u%20logo.jpg" alt="U4U Logo" /></a>
</div>
<div class="social">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/unified4unifat" id="twitter" class="imglink" target="_blank"><span></span></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/UnifiedforUNIFAT" id="facebook" class="imglink" target="_blank"><span></span></a>
    <a href="http://unifiedforunifat.wordpress.com/" id="wordpress" class="imglink" target="_blank"><span></span></a>
</div>

<div>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/menutestpage.html">UGANDAN PROGRAMS</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">US MOVEMENT</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">MEDIA</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">DONATE</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

then this is my css for my homepage related to links:

```
a{
text-decoration:none;
}

a:link,a:visited{
display:block;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
background-color:#ffffff;
padding:3px;
width:160px;
color:#000000;
float:left;
font-size:.9em;
transition-property:all 2s 0;
}

a:hover{
background-color:#e6e6e6;
color:#000000;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

a:active{
background-color:#000000;
color:#ffffff;
border:none;
}

.imglink:hover{
background:none;
border-style:none;
```

}

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I took the code you provided and tried to duplicate your issue and was unsuccessful. I tried Firefox, Chrome and IE (versions 7-10) and could not reproduce the issue you are describing. With that said here are a couple of things you could try:

- Be more specific in your CSS call: #wrapper `.header .imglink:hover {etc...}`
- Turn off the borders for the image: `.imglink img {border:0;}`
- Make sure your website is using a [DOCTYPE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp)
- Try using border:0; to turn off borders instead of border-style:none;
- View the source code or use [FireBugs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firebug/) (or some other tool) to view your code on the webpage to see if you’re CSS or HTML is being altered or overwritten.

If none of those options work it would be helpful if you could share the public website address if possible. Also it helps to know what browser you are using and what version. Hope that helps.

Comment: hey thanks for looking into things, you can see my answer above, and for some reason when i turned it into a sprite image (because i wanted to create a rollover affect, the underline on a:hover went away.....odd....

Comment: well it stopped working again.....here is the link to the page: http://unifiedforunifat.com/redesign/homepage.html any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

so i finally found out the answer....it was this part of my code:

```
a:hover{
background-color:#e6e6e6;
color:#000000;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

i think that was code left over from previous things i was doing so it was even unnecessary...now that i think about it, it was left over from when i originally included my menu in the html document itself instead of the method i have not which is inserting the whole header via SSI, which will allow me to put i on all pages....

hope this can help someone in future!